# Draw a gradient along a curved chart line in a SwiftUI Chart?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, charts

How do I draw a gradient along a charts line in a SwiftUI Chart line chart?

I did find how to a gradient like this…

```
Chart {
                ForEach(viewModel.items) { shape in
                    LineMark(
                        x: .value("Shape Type", shape.createDay, unit: .day),
                        y: .value("Total Count", shape.value)
                    )
                }
                .interpolationMethod(.cardinal(tension: 3))
                .lineStyle(StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 6, lineCap: .round))
                .foregroundStyle(
                        .linearGradient(
                            colors: [.accentColor, .clear],
                            startPoint: .leading,
                            endPoint: .trailing
                        )
                    )
            }
```

[image: linear gradient from left to right]

But what I want is to have the gradient follow the line itself and not just going from left to right. Is this possible?

Comment: i don't think it's possible to do what you want. it *is* possible to assign a different color to each segment of the line (to each `LineMark`), meaning you can fake a gradient, going segment by segment. but that requires some extra code and it has certain limitations. i can post an example if you like.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
.foregroundStyle(by: .value("Color", shape.createDay))
```

on the `LineMark`
The framework produces the gradient for you.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it's the same result when adding the style to the LineMark directly.

Comment: What is the problem with this solution?

Comment: Unfortunately the gradient still does not follow the curve. It covers the full height of the chart.

Comment: That‘s weird. Did you remove all other forgroundStyles? This method should tint each mark according to the createDay